# Stored procedure PHP - can't make another statement afterwards

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, pdo

I have this code. Everything works (and is correct) if I don't have the stored procedure call. But the stored procedure call blocks the next statement for some reason. How do I fix it?

```
// GET ID
$stmt = $db->query("CALL GetNewOrderNo");
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $orderid = $row["OrderId"];
}
$stmt->close();

// Add ID
$upd = $db->prepare("UPDATE orders SET orderid=? WHERE customer=? AND  info_date=? AND orderid='' LIMIT 1");
$upd->bind_param("ssi", $orderid, $customer, $datetime);
$upd->execute();
```

Comment: So... you close a statement ? `$stmt->close()` ? `PDOStatemement::close()` does not exists. You may want to close the cursor, which is `PDOStatement::closeCursor()`.

Comment: Normally not, that was just a try - doesn't make any difference :-)

Comment: @Zeratops This isn't PDO, it's MySQLi. `bind_param();` is a MySQLi function, and you can tell by the syntax ;-) So `$stmt->close()` does exist for that API.

Comment: @Qirel My bad, should have been precised in the tags !

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard You may want to add a `try{}catch(){}` wrapping your prepare/execute to see if this is returning an error.

Comment: It depends on how MySQLi is instructed to handle errors, in any case, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php is probably the best bet?

Comment: I tried all the error-handlers, I can't get it so anything. Yesterday though somehow I got it to print an error that said something like "out of <something>" like scope, it's like after I made a call to a stored procedure, every other call is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL stored procedures can return more than one result set, that is the reason to clear all results before do another query using the same connection.

Use `nextRowset()` after procedure call:

```
$stmt = $db->query("CALL GetNewOrderNo");
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $orderid = $row["OrderId"];
}
$stmt->nextRowset();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but it didn't work either. I just made an extra DB connection for the stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

try this
$stmt = $db->query("CALL GetNewOrderNo;");
adding ";"

Comment: `PDO::Query` handle the query and does not necessarily need to add this character.